# How to configure postgres to run only one version

Tags: linux, postgresql, command-line-interface, psql, ubuntu-20.04

I'm pretty new to using postgresql and seemed to have installed two versions that are running at the same time. Both 12 and 14.

Below is the list of commands that I've run, and the results they've yielded.

***From WSL-2 Ubuntu 20.04 CLI***

`➜ which psql`

```
/usr/bin/psql
```

`➜ pg_config --version`

```
PostgreSQL 14.4 (Ubuntu 14.4-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

`➜ psql --version`

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.4 (Ubuntu 14.4-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

***From psql***

`=# SHOW server_version;`

```
           server_version
------------------------------------
 12.11 (Ubuntu 12.11-1.pgdg20.04+1)
(1 row)
```

`=# SELECT version();`

```
                                                               version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.11 (Ubuntu 12.11-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I've have some persistent issues with my odoo 15 db and think this may be the cause but am unsure.

***Any recommendations on how to transition from 12.11 server to 14.4 server and remove 12.11 server would be greatly appreciated.***

Comment: Does 12.11 have data that needs to be preserved/migrated?  Do you know it got installed in the first place?

Comment: Ideally it would be preserved, but i'm also not afraid to lose it since I've had to drop my odoo db. I can't recall how I installed it, but I believe I installed with the following or similar command:
```apt-get install postgresql-14```

Comment: you should be able to run `apt list --installed` to see what is installed and `apt remove <package name>`. 
see here for removing packages: https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Comment: @Poiuy I understand that, but my concern is whether or not removing the package will effect my DBs

Comment: If you have data loaded into the database already you can do a pg dump to dump the contents of a database to a file. After reinstalling and launching the database you can load the data back. postgres docs for more details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Comment: Once you remove the software, obviously you won't be able to start the database anymore. So make sure you have a plain-text backup first, and that you are happy with it.  Also, if v14 is running on a different port, just removing 12 is unlikely to move 14 to the default port without additional action.

Comment: Thank you both. I will keep that in mind and take the following actions: 
pg_dump to ptf, sudo remove 12, change 14 default port, load pft into 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the above for the help!

Commands I ran to fix on Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows-11 WSL-2:

1. $ ~ `pg_dumpall > export.sql`
2. $ ~ `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*`
3. $ ~ `sudo apt-get install postgresql-14` (or -version preferred)
4. $ ~ `sudo -u postgres -i`
5. postgres ~ $ `psql`
6. #= `CREATE ROLE username superuser`
7. #= `ALTER ROLE username WITH LOGIN;`
8. #= `\password username;`
9. #= `\q`
10. postgres ~ $ `exit`

Answer (score 0):

I also ended up with two Postgres servers with different versions following a major Ubuntu upgrade. It turns out that there is a less radical way to get rid of the old version:

1. Back up all databases: `pg_dumpall -h localhost -U postgres -W > all_pg.sql`. This will ask for the `postgres` user's password as many times as there are databases in the cluster.
2. Stop the **new** (Version 14) DB cluster and drop it:
   `sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 14 main`
3. Upgrade the **old** (Version 12) cluster to Version 14: `sudo pg_upgradecluster 12 main`
4. Drop the **old** (Version 12) cluster: `sudo pg_dropcluster 12 main`
5. Remove the **old** Version 12 packages: `sudo apt-get purge postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12`

In summary, there is no need to `sudo apt purge` all Postgres packages and then reinstalling the most recent one.