# How to ensure a single version of Postgres is installed and run on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I have an Ubuntu 22 server on which I installed Postgres like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

It's been running for a while but I've just noticed I appear to have both versions 12 and 14 installed and running. For example:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c "psql"
psql (14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), server 12.12 (Ubuntu 12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
```

and:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
14  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

I've seen solutions for fixing this by dumping the data, uninstalling both versions, and installing the specific version ([such as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72822989/250962)) but my questions are:

1. Why did this happen in the first place?
2. What is the correct way to install Postgres on a new server to ensure only one version is installed? Every tutorial I've seen (such as [Digital Ocean's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04)) do what I did.

Comment: The version numbers suggest that one package is from 20.04 and another from 22.04. I've not seen that before, but I'd guess that something went wrong during the upgrade. The good news is that this won't be an issue on a "new server", since that one will probably be a fresh install.

Comment: Strange - I set this up as an Ubuntu 22 server a month or two ago. I didn't upgrade it.

Comment: That's unexpected. `12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1` suggests to me that the package is part of the 20.04.1 release. Though it's not impossible that the same package is still part of 22.04. And indeed: 22.04 only [has psql 14](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/postgresql-14) whereas 20.04 [has psql 12](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/postgresql-12).

Comment: I don't know how this happened in the first place, but it certainly wasn't from  merely doing `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`.  Maybe you can do some some grepping on /var/log/apt/ to try to piece together what really happened.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this could happen without either an upgrade from 20.04 --> 22.04 or a sources entry in /etc/apt  that points at a 20.04 repo.  This might  be a good time to consider changing to the Postgres community repo [Ubuntu](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). Then you will have all current supported Postgres versions available over the entire life of the Ubuntu version instead of being pinned to a particular version.

Comment: I must belatedly apologise for the confusion... reviewing my notes it turns out I *did* install Ubuntu 20! But at some point that upgraded to 22, and Postgres 14 was installed. I've no idea how or when or why. Thanks for your time all the same.

Comment: Same happened with me on ubuntu 18.04. I installed v12 `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12` and then `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev` I found v12 and v15 clusters. Don't know how to install specific versions of contrib and libpq-dev.